# "Not a single customer comes by." Is it correct?

Tags: grammar, adverb-placement

Suppose I am bored because there are no customers at my work. Can I write

> Not a single customer comes by.

How can we describe the basic grammar of this sentence? What kind of sentence part is *not* and why doesn't it need a verb, such as *does*?

Answer (score 1):

> **Not a single day** goes by when I don't think of that last-second goal against Chelsea.

This form of negation, where it is the subject which is negated, not the verb, is a stylistic choice that makes the statement more emphatic.

The alternative which that form supplants is:

> A single day **does not go by** when I don't think of that last-second
>   goal against Chelsea.

The form that negates the subject might be paraphrased so: of all the many days in the speaker's life, not even one of them is a day on which he does not think of that goal.

Comment: I am bored: Not a single customer has come by.

Comment: @Lambie, sometimes I have not a single clue what your comments are supposed to mean. If you're insisting that the simple present is invalid there, then you're wrong about that.  It could refer to a general state of affairs.  *How's your new job been? -- I'm bored. Not a single customer comes by (all morning,  on my shift, whatever).*

Comment: Yes, for an ELLer I would elaborate as you just did.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about the negation, not about the tense. *Why is "Not" in there without does?"*

Comment: I am not insisting. I am just saying it because to me, it is the most obvious in this context and the one the OP would probably miss....

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, we can regard "not" as an adverb that modifies the indefinite article "a", which carries the meaning of "one".   The adverb doesn't need a verb to modify because it has an adjective (or an article that plays an adjective-like role).   The phrasing "not a" can be interpreted as "not [even] one".